# Android app crashing when I try to open google maps activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

The app I have created loads fine, but every time I try to open the map activity from within, it crashes.. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?
I am relatively new to Android and still trying to get my head around activities and intents...

```
  07-28 16:18:37.042    189-22520/? E/ACDB-LOADER﹕ Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
  07-28 16:18:38.601    189-22597/? E/ACDB-LOADER﹕ Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
  07-28 16:18:39.061      724-841/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ cancelDelayedScan -> 2691
  07-28 16:18:39.062      724-841/? E/native﹕ do suspend true
  07-28 16:18:39.797    1839-1840/? E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK﹕ Failed to apply optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
  07-28 16:21:24.404  22719-22751/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: mmsconfig
  07-28 16:21:24.409  22719-22751/? E/Babel﹕ canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc nullnull
  07-28 16:26:45.488      724-841/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ cancelDelayedScan -> 2692
  07-28 16:26:45.489      724-841/? E/native﹕ do suspend false
  07-28 16:26:45.628    1839-1840/? E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK﹕ Failed to reset optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
  07-28 16:26:55.605      724-841/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ cancelDelayedScan -> 2693
  07-28 16:26:55.606      724-841/? E/native﹕ do suspend true
  07-28 16:26:56.338    1839-1840/? E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK﹕ Failed to apply optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
  07-28 16:29:08.282      724-841/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ cancelDelayedScan -> 2694
  07-28 16:29:08.288      724-841/? E/native﹕ do suspend false
  07-28 16:40:07.390    1321-1321/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
  07-28 16:40:07.390    1321-1321/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
  07-28 16:40:07.967  24924-24924/? E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
  07-28 16:40:08.680  25040-25085/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
  07-28 16:40:08.859    1704-2415/? E/MDM﹕ [151] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
  07-28 16:40:09.894  24793-24793/ribbit.khackett.com.ribbit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: ribbit.khackett.com.ribbit, PID: 24793
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ribbit.khackett.com.ribbit/ribbit.khackett.com.ribbit.MapPolylineActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class fragment
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class fragment
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
              at ribbit.khackett.com.ribbit.MapPolylineActivity.onCreate(MapPolylineActivity.java:50)
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
              at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.fk.a(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
              at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
              at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzr(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzvu(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2169)
              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
              at ribbit.khackett.com.ribbit.MapPolylineActivity.onCreate(MapPolylineActivity.java:50)
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
  07-28 16:40:19.002      724-832/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '378b103b ribbit.khackett.com.ribbit/ribbit.khackett.com.ribbit.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
  07-28 16:40:19.020    189-25259/? E/ACDB-LOADER﹕ Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
  07-28 16:40:20.497    189-25333/? E/ACDB-LOADER﹕ Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
  07-28 16:40:20.785      724-841/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ cancelDelayedScan -> 2705
  07-28 16:40:20.786      724-841/? E/native﹕ do suspend true
  07-28 16:40:21.635    1839-1840/? E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK﹕ Failed to apply optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="ribbit.khackett.com.ribbit"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:name=".RibbitApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <!-- android:theme="@style/AppTheme" -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MapPolylineActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".EditFriendsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_friends"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="ribbit.khackett.com.ribbit.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TFAddress"
            android:layout_width="231dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bsearch"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="onSearch"
            android:text="Search"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btype"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="74dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="changeType"
            android:text="Type"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="349dp"
            android:layout_height="469dp"
            tools:context=".MapPolylineActivity"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, line 50 of is MapPolylineActivity is:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

Answer (score 1):

First register your app in google developer console and then enable required apis for your app, then define below part in your manifest as follows:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

For more help, refer to this link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: Thanks Aakash... I have already created an API key - it was stored in google_maps_api.xml.  When I put the key directly into the manifest the map activity appears but the map does not show.  What would cause this?  A new error in the LogCat is saying 'Authorization failure.'

Comment: Have you enabled the api with SHA fingerprint and right package name.

Comment: I had it enabled yes.  I just created a new maps activity again and it is now working.  The problem may have been with the naming convention in the manifest.  Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First at all try to check your API Key to solve that error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

Use this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup